# Сериализация datetime.datetime при помощи jsonpickle кастомным хэндлером.

Tags: python, datetime

Привет! Появилась необходимость получать данные из БД, и отдавать их в виде json клиенту, в связи с чем, начал пытаться писать свой кастомный класс обработчик для типа datetime.datetime.

Следующий код:

```
import jsonpickle
import datetime

class DatetimeHandler(jsonpickle.handlers.BaseHandler):    
    def flatten(self, obj, data):
        return '/Date(%s+0800)/' % obj.strftime("%s")

jsonpickle.handlers.registry.register(datetime.datetime, DatetimeHandler)

print jsonpickle.encode(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Я пытаюсь вывести значение datetime в формане unixtime+timezone. В таком виде необходимо предоставлять значения для десериализации в C#.

но при попытке выполнить этот код появляется ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
  File "D:\date.py", line 10, in <module>
    print jsonpickle.encode(datetime.datetime.now())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jsonpickle\__init__.py", line 109, in encode
    return json.encode(j.flatten(value))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jsonpickle\pickler.py", line 141, in flatten
    return self._pop(self._flatten_obj_instance(obj))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jsonpickle\pickler.py", line 169, in _flatten_obj_instance
    flat_obj = handler.flatten(obj, data)
  File "D:\date.py", line 6, in flatten
    return '/Date(%s+0800)/' % obj.strftime("%s")
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

Answer (score 1):

очень странно, т.к. у меня тот же код выполнился успешно:

```
{"py/repr": "datetime/datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 14, 7, 2, 22, 738494)"}
```

возможно, просто не очень хорошая идея пытаться программировать под шиндовсом -- судя по трейсу что-то не так с системной локалью.
попробуйте выполнить тот же код под cygwin, если не поможет, то разверните для работы более подходящее окружение

Comment: У вас он тоже неправильно выполнился) Посмотрите мой хендлер DatetimeHandler :]

В любом случае, Я уже разобрался с проблемой неправильной сериализации)